# Add date to name of the folder created using mkdir

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script which when executed will produce some files.
I modified the script by adding the following two lines at its top

```
mkdir ABC
cd ABC
```

So that the formed new files will be inside the directory `ABC`. My question is how can I add current date to this directory name `ABC` such as it becomes `ABC_mar_26` (no specific criteria on date format, `ABC_03_26` is also okay) if I run the script on march 26th.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use `%Y-%m-%d` or `%F` if it's available. That format will display chronologically in a directory listing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get `ABC_03_26`:

```
mkdir "ABC_$(date +'%m_%d')"
```

If you want month name:

```
mkdir "ABC_$(LC_ALL=C date +'%b_%d')"
```

Note that `%b` give you locale's abbreviated month name, but with the first letter capitalized.

With `zsh`, you can:

```
mkdir "ABC_${(L):-$(LC_ALL=C date +'%b_%d')}"
```

or using [prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html):

```
$ LC_ALL=C; print -rl -- ${(L)${(%):-%D{%b_%d}}}
mar_26
```

Comment: I often find it more readable to put the constant string in the date format: `mkdir  $(date +'ABC_%m_%d')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete example application for your question, it might be also interesting for Windows/cygwin users. I have once created a `.bat` batch script to automatically backup files by creating a subfolder named with the current datetime. 
Firstly, variables are fetched from the `%time%` environment, and then formatted to evantually have a leading `0`. The strings are then concatenated to a new variable `%datetimef%` and passed to `mkdir`:

```
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%

set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%

set datetimef=%year%%month%%day%-%hour%%min%%secs%

mkdir version%datetimef%
cp *.pdf version%datetimef%/
```

Comment: This is a Unix and Linux site.